# Umbraco: How to insert partial view in template

Tags: templates, umbraco, partial-views

Using Umbraco v6 I've created a partial view that I want to insert into one of my templates. They say that you have to do it this way:

```
@Html.Partial("BlogCommentForm")
```

But it seems like the template does not render the razor code, since it comes out as html. And there is no button in the toolbar saying "Insert Partial View", only "Insert Macro".

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Is your Umbraco website running under WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Chris, If you got the solution kind answer....

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MVC try

@foreach (var item in list)
{

Html.RenderPartial("scriptfile",item);

}

Comment: i try this but i am getting this exception:
 Umbraco.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingException: Cannot bind source type <>f__AnonymousType0`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to model type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.